# How to run a laravel php app in AWS at low cost?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I will be lunching a classified Ad site written in PHP laravel and I am trying to figure out the cost to host on AWS. Users will be uploading images and doing alot filter search.

I was thinking of using 2 small EC2 instances as Web/App server and load balance them, and 1 EC2 for mysql
how many cpu and ram is enough for these ec2 instances?

I could also use a RDS instance but the cost maybe alot more.

Please advise on what tiers to chose and what the type of setup while keep cost low.

Budget is around $100/Month

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on the growth of the application, Also i suggest `S3` of amazon for storing assets like images etc.

The amazon initial tier is free both ec2 and and s3, You can find better info at their site. Also these are self expendables means the cost will increase with your usage.

Hope it helps.